# How can I extract sentences with years in them with a regex?

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I'm parsing Wikipedia articles.  I want to extract every sentence with a year in it.  The year can be anything from 1000 - 2012.  Below is the regex I've been trying, but I can't quite get it right.  Please help refine this.

```
$regex = '/\.\s.+\s[1|2][0-9]{3}\.\s/';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define a sentence as a run of non-period characters with a full-stop at the end:

```
[^.]+\.
```

(this has a few problems, of course, but they're nontrivial for *any* automated process to fix, so this will have to do). Then a number between 1000 and 2012 would be

```
\b(1[0-9]{3}|200[0-9]|201[0-2])\b
```

Combine them:

```
[^.]*\b(1[0-9]{3}|200[0-9]|201[0-2])\b[^.]*\.
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting sentences is a different story.

Hope it helps:

```
10[0-9]{2}|200[0-9]|201[0-2]
```

Now, how will you decide 1003 is a year and not any number, it's a different question.